# Cannot build android app using facebook SDK 4.5.0 due to layout_alignStart

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to use facebook SDK with my app.
While building I'm getting an error:

```
res/layout/picker_title_bar.xml:44: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignStart' in package 'android'
```

I'm trying to build against `android-16` or `android-18`, with `min-sdk` set to **8** and no go.
I'm wondering what's wrong with my configuration as it's impossible I'm the only one to have this issue.

What could have gone wrong?

The error is coming from here:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/com_facebook_picker_divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#40000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/com_facebook_picker_done_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/com_facebook_picker_done_button"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/res/layout/picker_title_bar.xml

The parent of this `LinearLayout` is `RelativeLayout`.

EDIT:
According to Facebook, the 4.5.0 API requires android-15 or newer to build.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

So I guess my min-sdk setting to 15 should be enough?

Comment: what is your min-sdk ?

Comment: It's android:minSdkVersion="8"  Does it matter? I think layout_alignStart  is there from the beginning and it's part of the RelativeLayout rather than LinearLayout as used in Fb sdk.

Comment: Yes. show the line of xml where you have put `alignStart`

Comment: I've updated the question. It's not me actually, it's part of the Facebook SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/res/layout/picker_title_bar.xml

Comment: Problem is `layout_alignStart` is supported from Android 4.2 (API level 17) for reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignStart

Comment: Hmm... I've looked at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html and thought that it was long before that. I've also found some posts saying that if this is specified in `LinearLayout` which is a child of `RelativeLayout` then it applies to the latter. Must have been wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain please move your comment to an answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `layout_alignStart` is supported from Android 4.2 (API level 17)

For further attributes, check [online docmentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignStart)